# How to force refetch of association results in Propel (also Doctrine) - Symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, orm, symfony1, propel

I have 2 entities: Parent with one-to-many relationship with Child.

I use the `$parent->getChilds()` automatically generated method by Propel to fetch all the childs.

Afterwards I manually add (or remove) some new childs in different method:

```
$child = new Child();
$child->setParentId($parent->getId());
$child->save();
```

Now if I recall the `getChilds` method I get the same original childs (and also no extra query to the database).

I understand that this is better behaviour and more efficient, but is there a way to force to refetch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$parent->reload(true)`

Should work in propel

Comment: Yep, `reload` is better, never heard about `rehydrate` :)

Comment: rehydrate was an accident - there *is* that function there somewhere - but it may have been removed :)

Comment: There's no reload function defined on Doctrine_Record, for the link see my answer.

Comment: @Maerlyn This anwser is only Propel related. As yours is only Doctrine related.

Comment: Oh my bad, I saw the doctrine tag and immediately assumed the question is about doctrine, while in the text the op says he's using propel.

Comment: @Maerlyn but he also asked for Doctrine (look the title) so you can bring back your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Never used it, but you may be looking for [`Doctrine_Record#refresh`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine1/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Record.php#L956).